# How can i add some text (i.e. kind of "about" info) in Preferences in Android

Tags: java, android, preferences, android-preferences

I'd like to add a short text (2-3 sentences) to my preferences screen (which is created using xml with PreferenceScreen, etc), in order to provide some kind of short help/description for the user.

I tried using `Preference`, i.e.  custom preference, but i cannot see more than 1 line in the title and more than 2 lines in the summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a lot of customization to a preference widgets.

Two options:

1) SMSpopup approach. Opening a new window with the information. Check the About preference.
Check the [src code](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/source/browse/trunk/SMSPopup/res/xml/preferences.xml?r=310).

2) Softkeyboard approach. Using the normal preference but setting it disabled. Check the [src code](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/browse/trunk/project/res/layout/prefs.xml?r=1465).